# Autocomplete in entry with existing value after an insertion is deleted in Tcl Tk

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I used the help of an existing code in tcl tk wiki to implement autocomplete feature in entry widget. http://wiki.tcl.tk/13267 (relevant parts cited below):

> ```
> proc autocomplete {win action validation value valuelist} {
>    if {$action == 1 & $value != {} & [set pop [lsearch -inline $valuelist $value*]] != {}} {
>      $win delete 0 end;  $win insert end $pop
>      $win selection range [string length $value] end
>      $win icursor [string length $value]
>    } else {
>      $win selection clear
>    }
>    after idle [list $win configure -validate $validation]
>    return 1
>  }
> ```
>
> Applied to an entry like this:
>
> ```
> entry .test -validate all -validatecommand {autocomplete %W %d %v %P $fruitlist}
> ```

So now if my data list has data like :

```
test of result
test again
rule and result
```

and I type '`te`' or '`t`' I get '`test again`' suggestion automatically in the entry. But when I delete the e from '`te`' I don't get any more suggestions like I was getting earlier when I only typed '`t`' unless I type another letter.

Is there any way to have the autocomplete work for the letters that remain in the entry after I delete some letter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The autocomplete code only does something significant after an insertion because it checks the *action* in the callback to see if it is `1`, which signifies an insertion. You need to extend the code so that it also does something when the action is `0`, i.e., after a deletion. Unfortunately, the simplest extension goes a bit wrong when you try to do this as when you delete the autocompleted text it has just inserted, the callback restores it for you immediately! The most basic workaround for that is to check that the text being actually deleted is one character long; if not, it's probably a deletion of a selection and shouldn't trigger completion.

Here's my updated version. It also includes a fix for a bug noted on the Wiki page with glob-special characters in the list of words.

```
proc autocomplete {win action validation delta value valuelist} {
    after idle [list $win configure -validate $validation]
    if {$value ne "" && ($action == 1 || ($action == 0 && [string length $delta] == 1))} {
        set pattern [string map {\\ \\\\ \[ \\\[ \] \\\] * \\* ? \\?} $value]*
        set pop [lsearch -inline $valuelist $pattern]
        if {$pop ne {}} {
            $win delete 0 end
            $win insert end $pop
            $win selection range [string length $value] end
            $win icursor [string length $value]
            return 1
        }
    }
    $win selection clear
    return 1
}
```

An extra argument (`delta`) was added in order to support determining how much text was deleted, which needs to bind to the `%S` substitution in the validation callback script, e.g., as below:

```
entry .test -validate all -validatecommand {autocomplete %W %d %v %S %P $fruitlist}
```

---

A much more correct fix for the autocompletion is to maintain a state model to determine whether the text being deleted was inserted through autocompletion with the previous action, or if it was done through different user actions, so allowing disabling of autocomplete on delete only when it is autocompleted text that is removed. But that's *really* complicated.